# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0 using GeckoDriver Firefox and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class OpenBrowser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\StudyPooja\\geckodriver.exe");
        System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "C:\\StudyPooja\\Mylog.txt");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

The Error I'm getting is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:14170
>   Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z'
>   System info: host: 'D790-18', ip: '192.168.43.66', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
>   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
>       at OpenBrowser.main(OpenBrowser.java:13)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:14170
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:242)
>       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:14170 
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z' 
System info: host: 'D790-18', ip: '192.168.43.66', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31' 
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver at
```

...implies that the *GeckoDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Firefox Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.14.0** of **2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z** which is more than **a year** older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_31** which is pretty ancient.
- Your *GeckoDriver* version is unknown to us.
- Your *Firefox* version is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u31* , *Selenium Client v3.14.0*.

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [GeckoDriver v0.26.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0) level.
- GeckoDriver is present in the desired location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v70.0*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.